# How to scope a viewModel to a Dialog Composable Function which is not related to NavHost

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am using Android compose and view model and I have a ViewModel that is scoped to a single Composable function which is a bottom sheet view, which is inflated using [BottomSheetScaffold](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#bottomsheetscaffold) and I inject the ViewModel inside the Composable function using [viewModel](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#viewmodel) but I have a problem that `viewModel` function returns the same viewModel instance created before when I open the bottom sheet again.

In other words how to scope the ViewModel to a Dialog Composable function which is not related to NavHost and backStack

```
@Composable
 fun ComposableExample(
) {
    val viewModel: ExampleViewModel= viewModel() // createdOnlyOnce and always returns old instance
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/165642391), Compose does not offer any mechanism to scope ViewModels to an individual `@Composable` - any ViewModels you create outside of a `NavHost`'s destination is scoped to the activity/fragment that contains your `ComposeView`/where you call `setContent` and, thus, lives for the entire lifetime of your Compose hierarchy - that's why you always get the same instance back.

Note that Navigation Compose has existing feature requests for [supporting dialog destinations](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179608120) and for [supporting `BottomSheetScaffold`](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180247978), which would bring the same scoping of ViewModels and state to those types of destinations as well. You should star those issues to get updates and indicate your interest (which then helps prioritize that work).

Comment: Similar use case: navigation based on pager, where pages are added dynamically and each page as separate @Composable with different ViewModel's. Do I understand it correctly that current ViewModel architecture doesn't support it and there are no plans for it? Is there a way to recreate custom VM scoping and achieve similar effect to NavHost?

Comment: @MTomczyński - Compose does not have the APIs required to scope ViewModels to individual composables at this time, that's correct. You'd want to star the issue linked if that's important to you.

Answer (score 1):

This library scopes ViewModels or any other object to the lifecycle of a Composable using the call `viewModelScoped` (or `rememberScoped`)

https://github.com/sebaslogen/resaca

```
@Composable
fun ComposableExample(
) {
    val viewModel = viewModelScoped { ExampleViewModel() } // created Only Once and always returns old instance
}
```

PS: It also supports an optional key, in case you want to have multiple ViewModels of the same type with different data, like `viewModelScoped(myId) { ExampleViewModel(myId) }`